# Home Button in Lock Screen App

Tags: android, homescreen

How home button is disabled in this Lock Screen app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appershopper.ios7lockscreen
I know that this app is created as launcher but how can I get to know when user click home button in Lock Screen Activity and when in home screen?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot listen to the home button press event in Android for obvious reasons. As a user, I wouldn't like that.

However, if you want your activity to be triggered when the home button is pressed (similar to how launcher apps work), you can add an intent filter to that activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks I know this but if You look on this Lock Screen it close automaticaly when user click home button on home screen and dont do anything when user click in lock screen app. Can I gain this result using ActivityManager and check which application is on Top?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Could you elaborate it further?

Comment: Maybe that Lockscreen app is closing itself in its onPause() method?

Comment: I give You example. Screen is locked -> User hit power button -> My Lock Screen App is launching user can unlock screen when he enter corect PIN, user cant unlock (put my Lock Screen App to backgroun) presing home button. Screen is unlocked user is using Chrome for example, when home button is presed default android launcher is being used and user return to homescreen.